# Object Not Instantiating (C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I am coding a tower defense game in Unity, and I've ran into a snag while trying to figure out a way to place towers. My idea is to be able to click an art asset in the game when the player has a certain amount of points, and it replaces that art asset with a tower. Unfortunately, even when the player has the right amount of points, the object does not instantiate. I have made sure to link the prefab to the script, but it doesn't work. I'm stumped, the logic of the code seems right but maybe someone can help me figure out what's wrong here.

```
public class PointManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int pointCount;
    public Text pointDisplay;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        pointDisplay.text = "Points: " + pointCount;
    }
}

public class PlaceTower: MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject Tower;
    private GameObject firstTower;
    int placeCost = 25;
    private PointManager pointsGained;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        pointsGained = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Point").GetComponent<PointManager>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        if (pointsGained.pointCount >= placeCost)
        {
            firstTower = Instantiate(Tower, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            //Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For reference, I used the following links for research:
https://www.raywenderlich.com/268-how-to-create-a-tower-defense-game-in-unity-part-2
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html

Comment: First, let's do some debugging. Are you sure that your `Instantiate` code is hit ? You could maybe do some logging in the console, or setting a public variable to true and show it in the inspector.

Comment: Also, Is your PlaceTower script correctly assigned to something where there will be a MouseDown event ? (sorry if this seems obvious, but currently we don't have your work under the eyes)

Comment: Wish there was a way to send a picture through here... This script is linked to a prefab asset placed on the map. Think of it like a mound where when you click on it, a tower is supposed to be built. That's what the MouseDown event is supposed to be for.

I'm not fully sure the Instantiate code is being hit. The code I have does allow the program to be run without errors in the console, but the objects simply don't appear in the game.

Comment: Can you insert a `Debug.Log("Mouse down inside if");` just before the `Instantiate` call ? and also a `Debug.Log("Mouse down")` before the `if`? The you should be able to see in the Unity console if the event is being hit, and if the `if` block is being hit.

Comment: (BTW, I don't think it's necessary, but you can insert a picture link, there is a button for that, if you edit your question)

Comment: Unrelated to the other messages : I think you should replace `public GameObject Tower;` by `public Tower Tower` (provided `Tower` is the name of your prefab).

Comment: So, I did that you said with putting the debug.log commands in front of certain actions. It seems like it's not registering my mouse clicks at all over the mounds, regardless of whether it has 25 points or not. Knowing that, perhaps the best course of action would be replacing OnMouseDown with a GetButtonDown or something similar.

The prefab in question is something like Sand Tower or First Tower, since it's the first tower and then there's another one that it can be upgraded to.

Comment: Also, I'd like to say that I appreciate you being quick and cordial with your comments!

Comment: no problem, I appreciated your reactivity as well. A last thing before I'll switch off, I cannot make an answer out of that, but maybe check that your object has a `Collider`, as described here : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html . there are also a couple of conditions written down there.

Comment: It's alright that you couldn't make an answer of it, because it turns out that wasn't the right one. Making it Input.OnButtonDown("Fire1") and putting it in the void Update function automatically places towers on both mounds now when the player hits 25 points. Also, yes, both towers have circle colliders that are meant to serve as a radius for them to shoot enemies when they're in range. These do not have the IsTrigger checkbox marked though.

Comment: I just got it. I'll be putting the answer down in a moment. Thank you so much for your help, Pac0, wish I could vote on your great responses!

Answer (score 0):

I got it. The problem was not with my code, but with my prefabs. In the documentation, I misread that `OnMouseDown` works on objects with colliders. While I had set up a circle collider on the object I was trying to instantiate, I had failed to put one on the object I was trying to instantiate from. Doing so fixed the problem immediately. A simple mistake that I would have completely glanced over had it not been for a second opinion. Thank you, Pac0!